Can a thunderstorm affect a satellite in low earth orbit?
Clouds build up strong static electric charges. Magnetism is an emergent phenomenon of the length contraction of electric fields. Due to the strength of EM interaction, even very slow movement can result in strong magnetic fields, such as that caused by electrons moving at drift speed through the wires of electromagnets.
So, wouldn't satellites be subject to easily detectable magnetic forces from clouds due to their high speed around the earth, if they were to pass over a thunderstorm?
